# PowerShell run php and get php echo/print_r/error in variable

Tags: php, powershell

I make a script in php which echo error if any but PowerShell don't show anything, part of script is

```
php C:\xampp816\htdocs\intaxingnew\php\karl\setup\autosetup.php
```

That don't do anything

I try to make then variable

```
$php =php C:\xampp816\htdocs\intaxingnew\php\karl\setup\autosetup.php
Write-Host $php
```

That don't work this is script that check for any update in folder and run php script as below

```
try
{
  $watcher = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property @{
    Path = $PSScriptRoot
    Filter = '*.php'
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName, [IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite 
  }

  $action = {
    php C:\xampp816\htdocs\intaxingnew\php\karl\setup\autosetup.php
    Write-Host 'Change'
  }
  $handlers = . {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Changed  -Action $action 
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created  -Action $action 
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Deleted  -Action $action 
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Renamed  -Action $action 
  }
  $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
  Write-Host "Watching for changes to $Path"
  do
  {
    Wait-Event -Timeout 1
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
  } while ($true)
}
finally
{
  $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
  $handlers | ForEach-Object {
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $_.Name
  }
  $handlers | Remove-Job
  $watcher.Dispose()
  Write-Warning "Event Handler disabled, monitoring ends."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In an `-Action` script block passed to [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent), success-stream (and error-stream) output does *not* surface automatically in the console.

  - You need to call [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) on the event-job object returned by the original `Register-ObjectEvent -Action` in order to collect such output on demand.
- However, [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) and [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host) *does* surface instantly (as does - curiously - output sent to all [PowerShell streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) other than the success and the error stream).

  - Therefore, you *should* see output from `Write-Host $php`, but only (a) if the event actually fires and (b) if the PHP script whose output is captured in `$php` produces *stdout* output (which gets mapped to PowerShell's success stream).
  - If the event fires and your PHP script produces visible output when called *directly*, the implication is that it produces only *stderr* output; to make this output visible, merge the stderr output into the success output stream with [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) `2>&1`, and pipe the result to `Out-Host` to surface it instantly (but note that you won't be able to *capture* the output then):

```bash
$action = {

  # Merge stderr into PowerShell's success stream (where stdout
  # goes by default) with 2>&1, and force instant display with Out-Host.
  php C:\xampp816\htdocs\intaxingnew\php\karl\setup\autosetup.php 2>&1 | Out-Host

  Write-Host 'Change'

}
```